# No such file or directory appcenter.podspec.json in CocoaPods/CocoaPods

Tags: react-native-ios

trying to install Microsoft Appcenter for react-native iOS. I got this error:

> We couldn’t find any issues matching 'No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/userName/Documents/Repo/bookombo-app-new/ios/Pods/Local Podspecs/appcenter.podspec.json' in CocoaPods/CocoaPods' after running Pod install since Updating react-native to 0.60.

"appcenter": "2.4.0", 
"react-native": "0.60.6",

Comment: I got this error today as well since I did `pod update`

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by making appcenter-pre-build.sh
and 
only adding these two lines

gem uninstall cocoapods

gem install cocoapods -v 1.7.5

Answer (score 1):

Run the following cmds

```
yarn remove appcenter appcenter-crashes 
cd ios && pod install && cd ..
yarn add appcenter appcenter-crashes
cd ios && pod install && cd ..
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating cocoapods to the latest version (in my case1.8) solved the problem for me :)